# How do I change icon size in folders?

Tags: 14.04, icons

Is it possible, and how do I change icon size in my folders in Ubuntu 14.04?  This was part of the folder menu in 12.04, but is missing in 14.04.

Comment: use ctrl+mouseWheel or on touchpad use Ctrl+TwoFingerScroll

Answer (score 2):

You can also use these keyboard shortcuts to zoom in and out.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the size (zoom in)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the size (zoom out)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to revert to normal size

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and scroll.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: appreciated-thx